# Why do I get "uninitialized value" warnings when I use Date::Manip's sortByLength?

Tags: perl, warnings

How might this block of code in *Date/Manip.pm* from the [Date::Manip](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Date-Manip) module:

```
#*Get rid of a problem with old versions of perl
no strict "vars";
# This sorts from longest to shortest element
sub sortByLength {

  return (length $b <=> length $a);
}

use strict "vars";
```

I get this warning:

```
Use of uninitialized value in length at /perl/lib/perl5.8/Date/Manip.pm line 244.
```

Comment: That's a warning, not an error, and it can be solved by not passing "undef" to that function.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not actually located there; the function is just being called with invalid (undef) parameters. To get a better trace of where it came from, try this:

```
$SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
  require Carp;
  Carp::confess("Warning: $_[0]");
};
```

This will print a stacktrace for all warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Either `$a` or `$b` are undef. Check the list you are feeding to the sort that uses this subroutine to see if you have an undefined value.

How are you using this code?

Answer (score 0):

If warnings for uninitialized diagnostics were enabled (perhaps via blanket `-w` or `use warnings;`) and if *sortByLength* were somehow called as a normal subroutine, rather than as a `sort {}` function, you would likely see this error:

```
$ perl -Mwarnings=uninitialized -e 'sub sbl { (length $b <=> length $a) } sbl' 
Use of uninitialized value in length at -e line 1.
Use of uninitialized value in length at -e line 1.
```

Here I get two warnings, because both `$a` and `$b` are uninitialized.  Hard to say without more context.