# Why do I get “uninitialized value” warnings when I use Date::Manip’s UnixDate in a sort block?

Tags: perl, sorting, date-manipulation

> Related/possible duplicate: [Why do I get "uninitialized value" warnings when I use Date::Manip's sortByLength?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263943/why-do-i-get-uninitialized-value-warnings-when-i-use-datemanips-sortbylength)

This block of code:

```
my @sorted_models = sort { 
    UnixDate($a->{'year'}, "%o") <=>
    UnixDate($b->{'year'}, "%o") 
} values %{$args{car_models}};
```

kept generating the following <s>error</s> warning:

```
Use of uninitialized value in length at /.../Date/Manip.pm line 244.
```

[Date::Manip](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Date::Manip) is a CPAN module.  And line 244 of Date::Manip is found within the following block of code:

```
# Get rid of a problem with old versions of perl
no strict "vars";
# This sorts from longest to shortest element
sub sortByLength {
    return (length $b <=> length $a);
}
use strict "vars";
```

But then including this (printing out the actual Unix Date value to the console in the logger) before the block of code to sort the values:

```
foreach (values %{$args{car_models}}) {
    $g_logger->info(UnixDate($_->{'year'},"%o")); 
}
```

removed the <s>errors</s> warnings entirely. Why? And what is a good fix instead of doing all these logging statements?

NOTE: None of the sorted values are undefined because when I printed them out in the logger, I could see that every one of them had a numerical value.

Comment: Can you put your logging statement in the sort block to see the actual values of $a and $b?

Comment: Also I would rather not touch any code in the CPAN module

Comment: I meant your sort block, not Date::Manip's. Something like
use Data::Dumper;
my @sorted_models = sort { 
print Dumper {a => $a, b => $b};
UnixDate($a->{'year'}, "%o") <=>  UnixDate($b->{'year'}, "%o") }                      values %{$args{car_models}};

Comment: Does the error show up with any data set? Is there a minimum reproducible test case?

Comment: So I added that line of code to dump my data:

 my @sorted_models =    sort { $g_logger->info(Dumper{a=>$a,b=>$b});
                        UnixDate($a->{'year'}, "%o") <=>
                        UnixDate($b->{'year'}, "%o"); }
                        values %{$args{car_models}};

I was able to dump $a and $b ONCE, then I got the error like >50 times, followed by a dump of $a and $b for 20 or so times (I have 10 elements in my array)

Comment: What the heck are you doing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267706/perl-hash-ref-error

Comment: Here is how my data structure looks like:

{
          'four-wheel' => 'true',
          'description' => 'Lightning fast',
          'producer' => {
                        'name' => {}
                      },
 
          'year' => '2009-08-07T22:31:06Z',
        };

Answer (score 1):

I am going to one last time try to answer this as clearly as possible.

First, if all timestamps are like `2008-08-07T22:31:06Z`, there is no need to map them through `UnixDate` as standard `sort` using `cmp` will sort them correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use Date::Manip;

my %args = (
    car_models => {
        a => { year => '2009-08-07T22:31:06Z' },
        b => { year => '2008-08-07T23:31:06Z' },
        c => { year => '2008-08-07T21:31:06Z' },
    },
);

my @sorted_cmp = sort {
    $a->{year} cmp $b->{year}
} values %{ $args{car_models}};

print "Sorted *without* using UnixDate:\n";
print Dumper \@sorted_cmp;

my @sorted_dm = sort {
    UnixDate($a->{year}, '%o') <=> UnixDate($b->{year}, '%o')
} values %{ $args{car_models}};

print "Sorted using UnixDate:\n";
print Dumper \@sorted_dm;
```

Output (after setting `TZ` in `cmd` to placate [`Date::Manip`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Date::Manip)):

```
C:\Temp> cars
Sorted *without* using UnixDate:
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'year' => '2008-08-07T21:31:06Z'
          },
          {
            'year' => '2008-08-07T23:31:06Z'
          },
          {
            'year' => '2009-08-07T22:31:06Z'
          }
        ];
Sorted using UnixDate:
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'year' => '2008-08-07T21:31:06Z'
          },
          {
            'year' => '2008-08-07T23:31:06Z'
          },
          {
            'year' => '2009-08-07T22:31:06Z'
          }
        ];
```

*No warnings*, *no errors* ... *Ergo*, all you have put on this page is one big mess of a red herring. Besides, this still does not explain where the `1249998666` in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267706/perl-hash-ref-error) came from.

Comment: H-ha, that's easy one. He put unix timestamps (product of UnixDate) into an array of supposedly hash references of automotive data and later he tried to operate them as if they are hash references:
push(@not_sorted_models, UnixDate($_->{'year'},"%o"));
hence the error Can't use string ("1249998666") as a HASH ref

Comment: @zakovyrya precisely why I have been asking the OP to show the actual data structures and code he is using and trying to discourage others from going on a wild goose chase with the fragments he has posted in three separate questions so far.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür: Sometimes it adds to fun :) Isn't that what this site is all about?

Comment: Thanks for everything.  I feel like I just pissed off a few people. The string would be the UnixDate value of a year field in the automotive data.

I was thinking UnixDate($_->{'year'},"%o") would return a straight-up integer and not a hash ref, so I thought I was operating with a number.

Comment: Yes YYMMDD form of the date will allow you to sort correctly. I thought an integer comparison would be safest.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001101.html *Stackoverflow is sort of like the anti-experts-exchange ... with the ultimate intent of collectively increasing the sum total of **good programming knowledge** in the world. ... Better programming is our goal.* Emphasis mine.

Comment: @Kys: No, that's exactly what UnixDate returns - straight-up integer,
probably what you intended to do is to convert your datastamps into integers, in this case you had to do 
$_->{year} = UnixDate($_->{year}, '%o');
push @not_sorted_models, $_;

Comment: @Kys regardless of what you thought one fact remains: It is not possible to reproduce your problem with the information you posted.

Comment: @zakovyrya: Yes, that makes more sense that I would want to insert the whole structure into the array if at the end of my sorting process I wanted to determine the make of the car with the "top" year. Now what if I just wanted to insert the year values (after converting into UnixDate form)

@Sinan Ünür: Hopefully the emphasis will be mine one fine day. :)

Answer (score -2):

Something is wrong with Date::Manip in the way it localizes special variables.
Try to call Date_Init() before you do sorting. It seems to solve the problem:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use Date::Manip qw(UnixDate Date_Init);
my $cars_ref = {
    mazda  => {model => 'mazda', year => '2008' },
    toyota => {model => 'toyota', year => '2001' },
    mitsu  => {model => 'mitsu', year => '2005' }
};

Date_Init(); # Initialize Date::Manip first!

my @models =
  sort {
    UnixDate( $a->{year}, '%o' ) <=> UnixDate( $b->{year}, '%o' );
  } values %$cars_ref;
print Dumper \@models;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'model' => 'toyota',
            'year' => '2001'
          },
          {
            'model' => 'mitsu',
            'year' => '2005'
          },
          {
            'model' => 'mazda',
            'year' => '2008'
          }
        ];
```

Comment: A real question is why anyone would want to map the years above through `UnixDate` to sort.

Comment: Besides, omitting the `Date_Init()` call above does not give rise to uninitialized value warnings. On Windows, it pukes because it can't figure out the timezone. Setting `TZ` in the shell fixes that. On Linux, the code above runs fine without the `Date_Init()`. So, your answer does not seem to be related to the OP's problem.

Comment: Why wouldn't anyone want to map the years above through UnixDate to sort?

Comment: Actuall zakovyra's solution took away my warnings.

Comment: @Kys There is no need to map years such as `'2001'`, `'2005'` and `'2008'` through `UnixDate` because they will sort just fine using regular `<=>` (or even `cmp`). No one can know what is going on with your code and data because you have not posted a short self contained script that works on a small section of your data. All we have are bits and pieces here and there and this is a consistent theme across your three posts on seemingly the same issue.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür I put it merely as an illustration due to lack of actual data, which wasn't available by that time

Comment: @zakovyrya I understand why you did what you did.

Comment: @zakovyrya However, note http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Date::Manip *The above routines all check to make sure that Date_Init is called. If it hasn't been, they will call it automatically. As a result, there is usually no need to call Date_Init explicitly unless you want to change some of the config variables*

Comment: @Sinan Ünür: Oh right I was still thinking you were referring to the years as timestamps as I had given in my previous example. But given the data structure I posted, is that sufficient information to work off on? If so, why is it that Date_Init() was able to remove all the warnings? Or is more information required for that?

Comment: @Kys @Sinan Ünür: As I said before it's probably because of the way they localize/do not localize special variables - $a and $b in this case. 
I noticed that they play well with $_: line local($_)=(); in sub Date_Init().
Although it's annoying, it's not that hard to fix it

Comment: @zakovyrya The `$a` and the `$b` in `package Date::Manip` have nothing to do with the `$a` and the `$b` in `package main`.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür: Maybe not, don't feel like digging into this right now

Comment: @zakovyrya -1. `$a` and `$b` in the sort block are package global.

Answer (score -3):

So I added that line of code to dump my data:

```
 my @sorted_models =    sort { $g_logger->info(Dumper{a=>$a,b=>$b});
                        UnixDate($a->{'year'}, "%o") <=>
                        UnixDate($b->{'year'}, "%o"); }
                        values %{$args{car_models}};
```

I was able to dump $a and $b ONCE, then I got the error like >50 times, followed by a dump of $a and $b for 20 or so times (I have 10 elements in my array)

Comment: Wait this isn't an answer. I meant to write it as a comment.